# How to use Android AutoCompleteTextView on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a `Xamarin.forms` project but i need to use `Android.Widget.AutoCompleteTextView` how can i apply that?
When i am trying to add  `AutoCompleteTextView UserNameAutoComplete;` to `ContentPage` i get the following error:

```cs
Content = new StackLayout 
{                   
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Padding = new Thickness(25),
    Children = 
    {
        UserNameAutoComplete,
        passwordEditor,
    }
};
```

> cannot convert from 'Android.Widget.AutoCompleteTextView' to
>   'Xamarin.Forms.View'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Android.Widget.AutoCompleteTextView` is a `View` from Android.

---

**Solution for PCL:**

You can't use platform specific `View's` on Xamarin Forms (PCL) `ContentPage`.

To use platform specific `View` you should use a [custom render](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).
There is a [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms-on-android/) from @JamesMontemagno that shows how to do what you need.

**This code is *draft exemple* please use it as such.**

1 - Create your own custom Xamarin.Forms control that will be renderered in Android as an `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```cs
public class AutoCompleteView : View
{   
    // Place need properties here.    
}
```

2 - In Android project add a renderer for `AutoCompleteView`:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AutoCompleteView), typeof(AutoCompleteViewRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public class AutoCompleteViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AutoCompleteView, AutoCompleteTextView>
    {    
        // Initialize the AutoCompleteTextView
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<AutoComplete> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
                return;

            var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteTextView(Forms.Context); 
            SetNativeControl (autoComplete);
        }

        // Use the control here.
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);

            if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
              return;

            // variable this.Control is the AutoCompleteTextView, so you an manipulate it.
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Solution for Shared Project:**

When using Shared Project there is a possibility to use [Native Embedding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/add-platform-controls/), like:

```cs
    ...
    var textView = new TextView (Forms.Context) { Text = originalText };
    stackLayout.Children.Add (textView);
    contentView.Content = textView.ToView();
    ...
```

Comment: could you please give a step to do that or add some code ..thanks

Comment: thanks jzeferion ..if you are familare with custom render , could you please add code for your answer contains steps ..

Comment: I've added a simple example to explain how render work. For more detail please read the full blog post.

Comment: i am trying to use your answer , actually the concept need to be how to embed native control on xamarin .forms

Comment: Yes thats what i posted. The sample i made and the blog post are about how to use a native control in forms.

Comment: @jzeferino its working fine in android, what should I do for iOS render?

Comment: @ZiyadGodil you should do something similar, but since iOS don't have a native `AutoCompleteView ` you should use a external library to support that for example [this](https://github.com/MarcBruins/MLPAutoComplete-Xamarin-iOS). You can also take a look at [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26929/autocomplete-in-xamarin-ios).