# How to create a native UWP view from Xamarin Forms view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am trying to create a **native UWP** view from a **Xamarin Forms** view. Following the example from [here](http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/), I managed to do it for Android and IOS.

More precisely, on IOS the conversion looks like this:

```
public static UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
{
    var renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer (view); 
    renderer.NativeView.Frame = size; 
    renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
    renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill; 
    renderer.Element.Layout (size.ToRectangle()); 
    var nativeView = renderer.NativeView; 
    nativeView.SetNeedsLayout ();

    return nativeView;
}
```

However, I need a similar approach for UWP.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I answered a similar question but on android, check if helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788731/xamarin-forms-how-i-could-using-android-widget-autocompletetextview-on-xamarin-f/37788847#37788847

Comment: Follow this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/renderers/

Comment: I need something closer to the android or IOS solution. I have updated my problem description with the IOS example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this by writing the following code for uwp:

```
internal static FrameworkElement ConvertFormsToNative(View view, Rectangle size)
{
     var renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(view);           

     view.Layout(size);

     return renderer.ContainerElement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but i would like to add an answer for the latest Xamarin version. I had same problem in 4.7 version and after digging into the Xamarin's source code, i found out that there is an extension converter method called [ViewToRendererConverter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/719fc7a604ff0cce8922d717c99bfb0fa17e35e0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ViewToRendererConverter.cs) can be utilized like below. It handles all childrens rendering and their sizes.

```
   var viewToRendererConverter = new ViewToRendererConverter();
    var frameworkElement = viewToRendererConverter.Convert(view, null, null, null);
```